# Is there any way to download original content of the "xampp/mysql" folder without completely reinstalling Xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp, webserver

I messed up my database in phpmyadmin by deleting root user, I don't have anything valuable there so I'd like to just wipe everything out and revert to how it used to be. Is there a place where I can download contents of a specific folders of an already installed instance of XAMPP such as xampp/mysql without having to use installer again?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to install a fresh version of xampp but if you still want to keep the previous version as it is then i would suggest you to install a new version of xampp in another directory and then copy the default sql directory to your previous xampp sql directory.